# How to record boot time?

Tags: systemd

I want to monitor boot time (the time needed by the system to boot) compared to software version installed (kernel and other software) day by day in order to have a look at boot performance for my arch-linux computer.

I use the systemd command `systemd-analyze time` to get the boot time.

My idea is to have a log with:

```
[day]
.......Boot time [s]:  2.145 (kernel) + 13.675 (userspace)
.......with kernel version 4.11.2
.......gnome-shell version 3.24.1
[day+1]
.......Boot time [s]:  3.145 (kernel) + 21.665 (userspace)
.......with kernel version 4.17.11
.......gnome-shell version 3.28.3
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Basic idea

I'd be tempted to do this as a systemd service that logs this to a file:

```
$ systemd-analyze time | sed 's/Startup finished in //;s/ +.*(initrd)//;s/ =.*$//'
442ms (kernel) + 10.224s (userspace)
```

This cuts the output of `systemd-analyze time` down to just the bits you want. The rest of the info you want is easy to come by via `uname` and `gnome-shell` command-lines' themselves:

```
$ systemd-analyze time | \
    sed 's/Startup finished in //;s/ +.*(initrd)//;s/ =.*$//'; \
    printf "kernel: %s\ngnome-shell: %s\n" "$(uname -r)" "$(gnome-shell --version)"
442ms (kernel) + 10.224s (userspace)
kernel: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
gnome-shell: GNOME Shell 3.25.4
```

#### More refined

As a script the above:

```
$ cat ./boottime.bash
#!/bin/bash

printf "[%s]\n" "$(date)"
printf ".......Boot time [s]: %s\n" "$(systemd-analyze time | sed 's/Startup finished in //;s/ +.*(initrd)//;s/ =.*$//')"
printf ".......with kernel version: %s\n" "$(uname -r)"
printf ".......gnome-shell version: %s\n" "$(gnome-shell --version)"

#[day]
#.......Boot time [s]:  2.145 (kernel) + 13.675 (userspace)
#.......with kernel version 4.11.2
#.......gnome-shell version 3.24.1
#[day+1]
#.......Boot time [s]:  3.145 (kernel) + 21.665 (userspace)
#.......with kernel version 4.17.11
#.......gnome-shell version 3.28.3
```

The output:

```
$ ./boottime.bash
[Sat Aug  4 14:34:40 EDT 2018]
.......Boot time [s]: 442ms (kernel) + 10.224s (userspace)
.......with kernel version: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
.......gnome-shell version: GNOME Shell 3.25.4
```

The unit file:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/boottime.service
[Unit]
Description=Boottime Service
After=systend-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/bin/boottime.bash
```

#### TLDR; parsing systemd-analyze time

The `sed` used above works as follows:

```
sed 's/Startup finished in //;s/ +.*(initrd)//;s/ =.*$//')"
```

- `s/Startup finished in //` - removes everything from left up to the word `in`
- `s/ +.*(initrd)//` - removes everything starting at `+` up to `(initrd)`
- `s/ =.*$//` - removes everything at the end of string, starting with `=` to the end of the line `$`

Comment: It looks good! I am not an expert of *sed*, can you explain the complex part `s/ +.*(initrd)//;s/ =.*$//` ?

Comment: @mattia.b89 - see updated section at end that explains

Comment: thank you, now it's clear! I don't have an *initrd* item...